# Object Smooth Movement through path

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a Pacman clone. The steps that I have accomplished are the floor, the maze, as also the pacman and the movement of pacman through wall paths.

The maze is in array format where the walls are represented as `"x"`. Also the movement should go with `wasd` keys from the keyboard. Currently the movement of the object is smooth and can walk in the path and change directions correctly only if I have the good timing with the hit.

I have also read this post [Relevant Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258111/pacman-java-movement-issues?rq=1) and I followed some of these techniques so that I can store the key presses. After I did that I don't think that something changed from the previous design. Also when I change to a direction that is not allowed it rotates to that direction and stops moving. I want to implement this like classic Pac-man game. Below is the code of my issue.

That's the **handleKeyDown** function where i check for key press.

```
function handleKeyDown(event) {
        currentlyPressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;

        if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == "A") {
            curr_key=temp;
            curr_key="A";
            memory_key = temp;
            pacRot = 0;

        }
        if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == "D") {
            curr_key=temp;
            curr_key="D";
            memory_key = temp;
            pacRot = 180;

        }
        if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == "W") {
            curr_key=temp;
            curr_key="W";
            memory_key = temp;
            pacRot = 270;

        }
        if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) == "S") {
            curr_key=temp;
            curr_key="S";
            memory_key = temp;
            pacRot = 90;

        }

    }
```

Now the function **can_move(key)** that checks if the object can move to a direction

```
        function can_move(key){
        if (key == "W") {
                if (stage[Math.round(y) - 1][x] == "x") {
                    y = Math.round(y);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (key == "A") {
                if (stage[y][Math.round(x) - 1] == "x") {
                    x = Math.round(x);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (key == "S") {
                if (stage[Math.round(y) + 1][x] == "x") {
                    y = Math.round(y);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (key == "D") {
                if (stage[y][Math.round(x) + 1] == "x") {
                    x = Math.round(x);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }
```

And finally the main moving function **move_conditions** that is called inside `tick()` after `drawScene()`

```
        function move_conditions(elapsed) {

        if(can_move(curr_key)==true){
            if(curr_key=="W"){
                ySpeed = 5;
                xSpeed = 0;
                y -= (ySpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            x = Math.round(x);
            }
            if(curr_key=="A"){
                 ySpeed = 0;
                xSpeed = 5;
                x -= (xSpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            y = Math.round(y);
            }
            if(curr_key=="S"){
                ySpeed = 5;
                xSpeed = 0;
                y += (ySpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            x = Math.round(x);
            }
            if(curr_key=="D"){
                ySpeed = 0;
                xSpeed = 5;
                x += (xSpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            y = Math.round(y);
            }

        }else if(can_move(memory_key)==true){
            if(memory_key=="W"){
                ySpeed = 5;
                xSpeed = 0;
                y -= (ySpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            x = Math.round(x);
            }
            if(memory_key=="A"){
                 ySpeed = 0;
                xSpeed = 5;
                x -= (xSpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            y = Math.round(y);
            }
            if(memory_key=="S"){
                ySpeed = 5;
                xSpeed = 0;
                y += (ySpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            x = Math.round(x);
            }
            if(memory_key=="D"){
                ySpeed = 0;
                xSpeed = 5;
                x += (xSpeed * 25) / 1000.0;
            y = Math.round(y);
            }
        }
```